# Unable to close modal after PDF Preview

Tags: jquery, pdf

I have this content in the modal where the user has the option if user wants to close the modal or print the content inside the modal.

Here's the btn:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary closemodal">Close</button>
```

And here's the script :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".closemodal").click(function() {
      $(".ModalLargeContent").hide('.ModalLargeContent');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Note 1: The modal is closing when I close it directly if I do not preview or click the function for print content. So I have this assurance that my scripts are working.

Note 2: Data-dismiss is the same thing as my script so both aren't working if I preview the pdf first before clicking CLOSED btn.

Comment: Why to write separate click function to hide the modal when bootstrap gives us default feature `data-dismiss="modal"` ? `<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary closemodal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>`

Answer (score 0):

minor fixing

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".closemodal").click(function() {
      $(".ModalLargeContent").modal('hide');
    });
 });
</script>
```

this is the correct one to hide

```
$(".ModalLargeContent").modal('hide');
```